# Trying to redirect the user to a specific page after form validation in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I am trying to redirect a user to a specific page after login form validation in my function.php file. Everything is working fine but, when I try to redirect the user to a specific URL, it's showing a "parser error".  Here is my code in the function.php file.

```
 add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record', function( $record, $ajax_handler ) {

  $form_name = $record->get_form_settings( 'form_name' );

      if($form_name=='userloginform'){
        $conn = new mysqli("localhost","mydatabase","myuser","mypass");
        $raw_fields = $record->get( 'fields' );
        $fields = [];
           foreach ( $raw_fields as $id => $field ){
               $fields[ $id ] = $field['value'];
               $email=trim($fields['email']);
               $password=trim($fields['pass']);
         }
       $result=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tablename where email='$email' ");
       $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
          if(!empty($row)){
               if($row['password']==$password){
                    header('Location: https://www.mywebsite.com');
                    exit;
            }
        else{
                $ajax_handler->add_error_message( 'Incorrect Password! Please try again...  
         );
                    
        }
        }else{
            
            $ajax_handler->add_error_message( 'Email adress not found! please enter a valid email address... ' );   
            }

}
```

when I enter the email and password it return the following error.
[image]

Comment: Have you already sent content to the browser and are trying to use `header()` after that fact, when you should be using `header` before sending any content (e.g make sure you don't have a space before `<?php`)? You should also use wordpresses redirect: `wp_redirect`

Comment: I am trying to store the variable value in a session variable like $_SESSION[]=$email before using header. Nothing else.

Comment: `parsererror` is very vague, what is the actual response from the server after clicking login, if possible could you please update your question with the contents of it including the status code

Comment: It's showing parsererror only as I have shown in the picture above.

Comment: When I enter the wrong email or wrong password then it shows a specific error like an Incorrect email or Incorrect password. But not redirect the user after the correct email and password.

Comment: Did you try with `wp_redirect` instead of `header('Location...`?

Comment: Don't try to use php session variables in WordPress.

Comment: I have removed the session variables and tried with the wp_redirect but now it's showing "error" in return.

Comment: One thing I want to clarify that I am using a child theme. Some other actions have already been added in the function.php. May be anyone of theme restricting the redirect.